# sample domain.xml that will work with arquillian

Tags: java, junit4, jboss-arquillian, glassfish-embedded

I've been testing my programs using arquillian for months now. I just recently installed jenkins in a glassfish container and have it build my project. I have a problem that arquillian is trying to use the same settings as the glassfish container that hosts jenkins, and it is failing my tests.

I tried using domain.xml as documented in https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/zgAO. The domain.xml I used is a sample copy of domain.xml generated by arquillian when it runs its tests 
(i.e. /var/folders/mf/tdymlzl95cj0fvw4vgxzqzj00000gn/T/gfembed5574188909570726432tmp/applications/)

my sample arquillian.xml content is

```
<container qualifier="glassfish" default="true">
    <configuration>         
        <property name="configurationXml">src/test/setup/domain.xml</property>
        <property name="resourcesXml">src/test/setup/glassfish-resources.xml</property> 
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Still it is failing.

All I wanted is to be able to configure ports that arquillian will use in embedded container so it will not conflict with the container that runs jenkins.

thanks in advance for any feedback or help.

Comment: adding the error that i'm getting
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: SEVERE: IOP00410016: Unable to create IIOP listener on the specified host all interfaces and port 3,700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 16  completed: No
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like you've run into [ARQ-856](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-856). You'll need to wait for the next release (most likely versioned as 1.0.0.Final) for the GlassFish container adapter. No promises on when this would happen, it is in the works.

Until then, you could use [this workaround specified in the comment](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-856?focusedCommentId=12682440&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-12682440) (specify the `bindHttpPort` value to be the same as the one in your domain.xml file for the HTTP listener).

Or, if you know how to build from the sources (a `git clone...` and a `mvn clean install` should do), you could build and use the current snapshot version.